# The variable is not accessing inside the barcode scanner function

Tags: angular

I am developing an ionic 2 app in which I'm using Bar code scanner code inside the for loop but the variable i is not accessible inside barcode function..

this is my barcodetest.ts

```
export class HelloIonicPage implements OnInit {
orderstring: string;
  orderarray: any;
  bartxt: any;
  pickuplist: any;

vendorbarcode(index, pickuplist) {
    this.orderstring = this.pickuplist[index].OrderId;
    if (this.orderstring !== '') {
      this.orderarray = this.orderstring.split(', ');
      for (var i = 0; i <= this.orderarray.length; i++) {
        console.log(this.orderarray[i]);  //here m getting the value

        BarcodeScanner.scan().then((barcodeData) => {
          if (barcodeData.cancelled) {

            return false;
          }

          console.log(this.orderarray[i]);  //here getting undefined

        }, (err) => {
          console.log(err);
        });
      }
    }
  }
}
```

this is this.orderstring = "12234, 12235";

I have tried this in some ways then also not getting result.. please help me sort this issue.

Comment: `this` variable is context dependent, in a subscribe callback it doesn't refer to your component anymore. Try to create another variable like `let self = this;` and use that instead of this.

Comment: As you suggested I used let self = this; but getting same problem..

Comment: Is anyone there..? Please help me sort this issue...